# Texture2D.ReadPixels not working on WebGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to read values from a render texture so I'm using ReadPixels:

```
var currentActiveRT = RenderTexture.active;
RenderTexture.active = _sim.CurrentTex;
 
_cashedTex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, _cashedTex.width, _cashedTex.height), 0, 0);
_cashedTex.Apply();
 
RenderTexture.active = currentActiveRT;
```

However it doesn't seem to work on WebGL. Anything I read from it on WebGL is just 0, while in the editor I get the actual values.

I get the following error in the Firefox console in my WebGL dev build: "Error: WebGL: readPixels: Invalid format/type pair". No error is given in the editor, this only happens in the WebGL build.

The rendertexture had format `RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat` and the `_cashedHeightsTex` has format `TextureFormat.RGBAFloat` (notice the A channel is placed different, but there is no RGBAFloat format for rendertextures :s)

Why does this happen? And how can I fix this?

Notes:

- What I'm doing is generating and simulating a terrain on GPU (the texture is a heightmap). I'm reading the height values to update the physics model, so I can raycast it.
- I also asked this on the [Unity Forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/texture2d-readpixels-not-working-on-webgl.428214/)
- I'm using Unity 5.4.0f3 and Firefox 48.0.2

Update:

I made a little test to see if it was only a problem with float-formats, and it does indeed seem so.

What it looks like in the editor: [image]

What it looks like in Firefox: [image]

And here you can see the WebGL buils: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10448192/ReadPixelTest/WebGL/index.html

You can download the source here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10448192/ReadPixelTest/ReadPixelTest.zip

Update: I submitted this as a bug to Unity and they said they were able to reproduce it and will look into it. So it seems it will be fixed in some future version hopefully.

Comment: I guess this would probably throw some exception or wouldn't work in the editor if not, but the texture has read/write enabled?

Comment: It has to have something to do with rendering order. Can you try reading pixels in the end of frame? `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();`

Comment: @GunnarB. I added info about the error, stupid I forgot to add it initially.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Trying that out now, but building is slow :P Will report back soon ;)

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Just tried that, but didn't work. Check out the extra error I added in the main post ;)

Comment: @GunnarB. I've been looking into the read/write setting, however it doesn't seem to be an option on textures you create in scripts. `_cashedHeightsTex = new Texture2D(_sim.GridPixelCount, _sim.GridPixelCount, TextureFormat.RGBAFloat, false);` However it does work in the editor, and `SetPixel` seems to work fine (no error in WebGL about it).

According to http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/531035/how-to-access-and-modify-the-readwrite-enabled-val.html a Texture2d is always read/writeable.

Comment: Seems like your format is not matching your type. If you google that error you get some links about that.

Comment: @GunnarB. Hmm yes, but nothing really helped there :s Nothing I find is for Unity, and I can't apply them to Unity, not enough options available in Unity it seems :(

Comment: What version of Unity and Firefox are you using?

Comment: @Programmer I'm using Unity 5.4.0f3 and Firefox 48.0.2

Comment: Add the following code to your project then compile to WebGL. Run it and let me know what the output is 

`if (SystemInfo.SupportsRenderTextureFormat(RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat))
{
    Debug.Log("Supported!");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("NOT Supported!");
}`

Comment: @Programmer I tried that and it says it's supported. I also tried the same for the RGBAFloat texture format and that's also supported.